# Select all rows after the LATEST row that has attributeA = 1

Tags: mysql

```
|------------------------------------------------|
| id |    user_id   | mes_date     |  attributeA |
|------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 8             | 2019-01-18  |      0      |  
| 2  | 12            | 2019-01-16  |      1      |   
| 3  | 12            | 2019-02-20  |      1      | 
| 4  | 12            | 2019-03-23  |      0      |  
| 5  | 9             | 2019-02-24  |      1      |  
| 6  | 9             | 2019-02-24  |      1      |  
|------------------------------------------------|
```

How can I do that with one query?

Basically it's "select all the rows of that user, after he had AttributeA = 1 for the last time"

In this case, I want to select user_id 12:

```
    |------------------------------------------------|
    | id |    user_id   |  mes_date    |  attributeA |
    |------------------------------------------------|
    | 3  | 12            | 2019-02-20  |      1      | 
    | 4  | 12            | 2019-03-23  |      0      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.mes_date, t1.attributeA
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, MAX(id) AS id FROM mytable WHERE user_id = 12
) AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.id >= t2.id
```